# SQL Server: stored proc tries to convert varchar OUTPUT into int @Return_Value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
create proc Sponsors.GetLightBoxAd
(
@SponsorID varchar(30),
@ADIDOut varchar(30) OUTPUT,
@UserID varchar(30),
@ProjectID varchar(50),
@PlatformID int
)
as 
begin
  SELECT TOP 1 @ADIDOut = AD.ADID --my output. AD.ADID is a varchar(30) column
  FROM Sponsors.AD
  WHERE AD.Active = 1 and AD.SponsorID = @SponsorID
  ORDER by NEWID() -- I want the first one picked at random
  IF ISNULL(@ADIDOut,-1) != -1 --if the result set wasn't null, run some update queries with the result
  BEGIN --These queries do not have output variables.
    EXEC Sponsors.proc1 @ADIDOut, @SponsorID
    EXEC Projects.proc2 @ProjectID,@ADIDOut,@UserID,@PlatformID 
  END --end the if
end --end the proc
go
```

This should return either a null value or a varchar.
However when I try to execute the query, SSMS auto-generates this code for me to run the query:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int, --Why is this here???
        @ADIDOut varchar(30) -- this should be my only output

EXEC    @return_value = [Sponsors].[GetLightBoxAd]
        @SponsorID = N'Alienware',
        @ADIDOut = @ADIDOut OUTPUT,
        @UserID = N'127.0.0.1',
        @ProjectID = N'TestProject',
        @PlatformID = 1

SELECT  @ADIDOut as N'@ADIDOut'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value --why is this here?

GO
```

And then it gives me an error because it appears to try to convert the result of ADIDOut into an int... Why is there an int @Return_Value variable and why is it trying to put my actual OUTPUT result into it?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: That's just the way SSMS generically generates EXECUTE statements for stored procs.   It shouldn't be causing any errors.  What is the error message you get?

Comment: @Rieekan SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @TabAlleman:
    Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetLightBoxAd, Line 16
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'GamingEvolved1' to data type int.
GamingEvolved1 is the ADID for the test sponsor I called.

Comment: Check the datatypes of the parameters for proc1 & proc2, and make sure one of them isn't expecting an int datatype where you are passing `ADIDOut`.

Comment: They are ok but your message gave me an idea and I figured out what was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in this line:

```
IF ISNULL(@ADIDOut,-1) != -1
```

It seems since I put just -1 without quotes as the comparison, sql reads this as an integer and cannot compare it to a nullable string so the error is raised. Putting the -1's into quotes fixes the error and the query runs. Thanks for the help!